# Dynamically resizing font to fit space while using Graphics.DrawString

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, system.drawing

Does anyone have a tip whereas you could dynamically resize a font to fit a specific area? For example, I have an 800x110 rectangle and I want to fill it with the max size font that would support the entire string I'm trying to display.

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(800, 110);

using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
using (Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 120, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
{
    Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 110);

    StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
    stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

    graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
    graphics.DrawString("Billy Reallylonglastnameinstein", font1, Brushes.Red, rect1, stringFormat);
} 

bitmap.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Fonts/" + System.Guid.NewGuid() + ".png"));
```

Obviously that whole name won't render in the space provided at the large font size. There has to be a simple way to do this?

Comment: Maybe use [`TextRenderer.MeasureText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4xdbe66.aspx) or [`Graphics.MeasureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx) and iteratively lower your font size until it fits?

Comment: @farina i change my answer and i think this solution can help you to solve it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should do a scale transform on `Font.Size` the following function is an example of doing that but you can improve it to apply better results.

Here is `FindFont` function which get a room and a text with prefered size and gives you a font in which you can set that whole text fits the room!

```
// This function checks the room size and your text and appropriate font
//  for your text to fit in room
// PreferedFont is the Font that you wish to apply
// Room is your space in which your text should be in.
// LongString is the string which it's bounds is more than room bounds.
private Font FindFont(
   System.Drawing.Graphics g,
   string longString,
   Size Room,
   Font PreferedFont
) {
   // you should perform some scale functions!!!
   SizeF RealSize = g.MeasureString(longString, PreferedFont);
   float HeightScaleRatio = Room.Height / RealSize.Height;
   float WidthScaleRatio = Room.Width / RealSize.Width;

   float ScaleRatio = (HeightScaleRatio < WidthScaleRatio)
      ? ScaleRatio = HeightScaleRatio
      : ScaleRatio = WidthScaleRatio;

   float ScaleFontSize = PreferedFont.Size * ScaleRatio;

   return new Font(PreferedFont.FontFamily, ScaleFontSize);
}
```

For your question you can call it like the following code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(800, 110);

using (System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
using (Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 120, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
{
   Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 110);

   StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
   stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
   stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
   graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;

   Font goodFont = FindFont(graphics, "Billy Reallylonglastnameinstein", rect1.Size, font1);

   graphics.DrawString(
      "Billy Reallylonglastnameinstein",
      goodFont,
      Brushes.Red,
      rect1,
      stringFormat
   );
}
```

Comment: How about `float ScaleRatio = Math.Min(HeightScaleRatio, WidthScaleRatio);`

Comment: This might get it close, but it seems like text wrapping can make this inaccurate.  It would be a good approach for a single line of text.

Comment: There could be a lot more options to do ... like text processing or even text2image algorithms and/or vice versa , it depends on programmers idea. upon my post it's clean and simple solution to do! and is just a base idea to improve!!!

Comment: I used this in my component: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891547/draw-character-in-center-of-custom-control-font-awesome-glyph Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Add `GraphicsUnit.Pixel` to `FindFont()` function return line. Without `GraphicsUnit.Pixel` system dpi will effect the drawn string. This is how the line will look like. `return new Font(PreferedFont.FontFamily, ScaleFontSize,PreferedFont.Style,GraphicsUnit.Pixel);`

Comment: @RijulSudhir Please explain more on Pixel unit system reproduce if you see any problem and post new answer to complete or correct my effort.Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @saeed I have posted as new answer.

Answer (score 4):

I've adapted Saeed's great function to more suit my requirements. Comments explain all:

```
    // You hand this the text that you need to fit inside some
    // available room, and the font you'd like to use.
    // If the text fits nothing changes
    // If the text does not fit then it is reduced in size to
    // make it fit.
    // PreferedFont is the Font that you wish to apply
    // FontUnit is there because the default font unit is not
    // always the one you use, and it is info required in the
    // constructor for the new Font.
    public static void FindGoodFont(Graphics Graf, string sStringToFit,
                                    Size TextRoomAvail, 
                                    ref Font FontToUse,
                                    GraphicsUnit FontUnit)
    {
        // Find out what the current size of the string in this font is
        SizeF RealSize = Graf.MeasureString(sStringToFit, FontToUse);
        Debug.WriteLine("big string is {0}, orig size = {1},{2}",
                         sStringToFit, RealSize.Width, RealSize.Height);
        if ((RealSize.Width <= TextRoomAvail.Width) && (RealSize.Height <= TextRoomAvail.Height))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("The space is big enough already");
            // The current font is fine...
            return;
        }

        // Either width or height is too big...
        // Usually either the height ratio or the width ratio
        // will be less than 1. Work them out...
        float HeightScaleRatio = TextRoomAvail.Height / RealSize.Height;
        float WidthScaleRatio = TextRoomAvail.Width / RealSize.Width;

        // We'll scale the font by the one which is furthest out of range...
        float ScaleRatio = (HeightScaleRatio < WidthScaleRatio) ? ScaleRatio = HeightScaleRatio : ScaleRatio = WidthScaleRatio;
        float ScaleFontSize = FontToUse.Size * ScaleRatio;

        Debug.WriteLine("Resizing with scales {0},{1} chose {2}",
                         HeightScaleRatio, WidthScaleRatio, ScaleRatio);

        Debug.WriteLine("Old font size was {0}, new={1} ",FontToUse.Size,ScaleFontSize);

        // Retain whatever the style was in the old font...
        FontStyle OldFontStyle = FontToUse.Style;

        // Get rid of the old non working font...
        FontToUse.Dispose();

        // Tell the caller to use this newer smaller font.
        FontToUse = new Font(FontToUse.FontFamily,
                                ScaleFontSize,
                                OldFontStyle,
                                FontUnit);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is just an update for @Saeed's `FindFont` function.

`GraphicsUnit.Pixel` needs to be added to `FindFont` function return line. Without `GraphicsUnit.Pixel`, system dpi will effect the drawn string. Problem will arise when the dpi of system and bitmap mismatches. You can see more detail in this [Windows DPI setting affects Graphics.DrawString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800264/windows-dpi-setting-affects-graphics-drawstring). Since GraphicsUnit of `PreferedFont` is already set to `GraphicsUnit.Pixel` and return font is not set with `GraphicsUnit.Pixel`. In this case text will go out of the `Room` dimension, if bitmap dpi is larger than system dpi and font size will go smaller than the expected size if bitmap dpi is smaller than system dpi. Here is the updated function.

```
    private Font FindFont(  System.Drawing.Graphics g , string longString , Size Room , Font PreferedFont)
    {
        SizeF RealSize = g.MeasureString(longString, PreferedFont);
        float HeightScaleRatio = Room.Height / RealSize.Height;
        float WidthScaleRatio = Room.Width / RealSize.Width;
        float ScaleRatio = (HeightScaleRatio < WidthScaleRatio) ? ScaleRatio = HeightScaleRatio : ScaleRatio = WidthScaleRatio;
        float ScaleFontSize = PreferedFont.Size * ScaleRatio;
        return new Font(PreferedFont.FontFamily, ScaleFontSize,PreferedFont.Style,GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
```

Comment: This is interesting. I’ve never had that issue, but I’m sure it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to bash against saaeds solution which is probably pretty awesome, too. But I found another one on msdn: [Dynamic Graphic Text Resizing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986765.aspx) which worked for me.

```
public Font GetAdjustedFont(Graphics GraphicRef, string GraphicString, Font OriginalFont, int ContainerWidth, int MaxFontSize, int MinFontSize, bool SmallestOnFail)
{
   // We utilize MeasureString which we get via a control instance           
   for (int AdjustedSize = MaxFontSize; AdjustedSize >= MinFontSize; AdjustedSize--)
   {
      Font TestFont = new Font(OriginalFont.Name, AdjustedSize, OriginalFont.Style);

      // Test the string with the new size
      SizeF AdjustedSizeNew = GraphicRef.MeasureString(GraphicString, TestFont);

      if (ContainerWidth > Convert.ToInt32(AdjustedSizeNew.Width))
      {
       // Good font, return it
         return TestFont;
      }
   }

   // If you get here there was no fontsize that worked
   // return MinimumSize or Original?
   if (SmallestOnFail)
   {
      return new Font(OriginalFont.Name,MinFontSize,OriginalFont.Style);
   }
   else
   {
      return OriginalFont;
   }
}
```

Comment: I also found this blog post (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeekImageProcessorLightweightImageManipulationInC.aspx) pretty useful. At the time I asked this question, saeed's solution was perfect, and I think all of these solutions are really on target.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution that support wrapping.

```
public static Font GetAdjustedFont(Graphics graphic, string str, Font originalFont, Size containerSize)
    {
        // We utilize MeasureString which we get via a control instance           
        for (int adjustedSize = (int)originalFont.Size; adjustedSize >= 1; adjustedSize--)
        {
            var testFont = new Font(originalFont.Name, adjustedSize, originalFont.Style, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            // Test the string with the new size
            var adjustedSizeNew = graphic.MeasureString(str, testFont, containerSize.Width);

            if (containerSize.Height > Convert.ToInt32(adjustedSizeNew.Height))
            {
                // Good font, return it
                return testFont;
            }
        }

        return new Font(originalFont.Name, 1, originalFont.Style, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
```

How to use:

```
var font = GetAdjustedFont(drawing, text, originalfont, wrapSize);
drawing.DrawString(text, font, textBrush, new Rectangle(0, 0, wrapSize.Width, wrapSize.Height));
```